# python getcwd of a subst ( O:\ )folder

Tags: windows, python-2.7

I am running a python script from a subst folder in windows:

```
c:\MyFolder\Tmp\Code\subst O: .
O:\script.py
```

script.py is running the ***getcwd*** (and ***abspath***) command and it needs the real folder name, but instead it shows O:.

Is there a way to get the real folder name (without running the ***subst*** command and iterating the drives) and use an ***getcwd*** alternative?

Comment: As far as Python (or any other program) is concerned `O:\\` *is* the real folder name. There is no way for programs to detect any difference. (Can you explain why using the folder is not an option?)

Comment: The native path of the working directory will be something like "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\MyFolder\Tmp\Code". If you open a handle to this directory via the `subst` drive "O:" and call `GetFinalPathNameByHandle`, Windows can reconstruct either the Volume GUID path or the DOS path. It gets the native device and file path via `NtQueryObject` and `NtQueryInformationFile`. Then it opens the mount-point manager "\Device\MountPointManager" to query the mapping from the native device path to either the "Volume{GUID}" name or the DOS logical drive letter (or folder if there is no drive letter mount).

Comment: In Python 3, `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` is wrapped as `os.path._getfinalpathname` (only for getting the final DOS path). It's used by `pathlib.Path.resolve`.

Comment: @eryksun perfect for my usage. thanks!

Comment: @tomalak As far as "any other program" is concerned, it does matter. For example, Docker can't share substed drives, and so in such a case getting the absolute, 'real' path is necessary. Its hitting me right now.. A "substed" folder name is not the *real* name, it's a *substituted* name. And as far as I'm concerned, the Python abspath is causing a *real* problem for me, for sure..! Is really the marked answer below, the only way??

Answer (score 1):

As marking comments as accepted answer is impossible, I will quote @eryksun's comments:

> The native path of the working directory will be something like "\Device\HarddiskVolume2\MyFolder\Tmp\Code". If you open a handle to this directory via the subst drive "O:" and call GetFinalPathNameByHandle, Windows can reconstruct either the Volume GUID path or the DOS path. It gets the native device and file path via NtQueryObject and NtQueryInformationFile. Then it opens the mount-point manager "\Device\MountPointManager" to query the mapping from the native device path to either the "Volume{GUID}" name or the DOS logical drive letter (or folder if there is no drive letter mount)
>
> In Python 3, GetFinalPathNameByHandle is wrapped as os.path._getfinalpathname (only for getting the final DOS path). It's used by pathlib.Path.resolve

Much appreciated, thanks.